# Group Instancing: How do animations behave?

Tags: animation, groups

I've yet to delve into animations with Blender, but something I'm curious about is what happens if one were to create a couple of basic meshes joined with bones, then animated. If another object is made from the instance, would it also have the same animation? If so, can the animation be different, or not be animated at all?

I'm mostly curious as I'm not sure whether to create a group instance for several identical objects that would be separately animated in the future.

Comment: Usually all instances will be the same as the group. Even linking won't help. If you want to have more of the same rig in a scene, you can duplicate the source file and link the group from diffrerent files each.

Comment: I assume that also means I cant simply group the meshes only, then create the bones afterwards for each individual mesh? Also, regarding duplicating files, you mean having one set of the mesh and bones in multiple separate .blend files and importing them all into the main project?